# Using grep to search for a whole word/phrase with only part

Tags: terminal, grep, cut

I am trying to fetch the current "Device Node" (for example disk0s4) for my Bootcamp partition on my MacBook Pro using the terminal command `$ diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep "Node"`. This works nicely. I want to create a program that does a few things to the partition/volume and because it could potentially change nodes (because I screw with my filesystem).

Thus I need to create a variable or store the value of the device node (and only the device node) so I can use it later. Here is what I have tried.

```
$ grepVar=$(diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep "Node")
$ A="$(cut -d'/' -f1 <<<"$grepVar")"
$ echo "$A hi"
   Device Node:               hi
```

The actual file reads as this when I run `diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep "Node"`:

> `Device Node:              /dev/disk0s4`

Obviously the `cut` cut out the wrong part, and kept the spacing. I experimented with a few other techniques but with no prevail. What would anyone recommend? The -o method just gave me part of the `/dev/disk0s4`, not the entire phrase/word. Would I just have to phrase it after "grepping" it? How?

Thanks a ton

Comment: could you clarify.. I am not sure which portion you need to be saved in variable.. `Device Node:` or `/dev/disk0s4` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `grep` is an acronym. Global Regular Expression Print -- like the command you might use in `vi` to list lines that match a regex.  Extra functionality like PCRE is not portable and may not be available in all systems -- or even in yours without software being installed.

Often `sed` provides the quickest or most succinct way to manipulate a stream of text. For example:

```
diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | sed -ne '/Device Node:/s#.*/##p'
```

This finds the line of text you're looking at, strips off everything up to the last slash, and prints the remainder of the line. Putting this in a variable is as simple as:

```
node=$(diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | sed -ne '/Device Node:/s#.*/##p')
```

or

```
read -r node < <(diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | sed -ne '/Device Node:/s#.*/##p')
```

You could alternately process the output in `awk` like so:

```
diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | awk -F/ '/Device Node:/ { print $NF }'
```

This, again, finds the line you're interested in, and prints the last field .. with field separators set to the forward slash.

If you REALLY wanted to use only `grep` for this, you could do some pipe-fitting:

```
diskutil info "BOOTCAMP" | grep 'Device Node:' | grep -o '/[^/]*$' | grep -Eo '[^/]+'
```

And of course, the final `grep` could be replaced with `cut -d/ -f2` if you wish.

Naturally, all of these fail if `BOOTCAMP` doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed and in depth answer.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS you could use `pcregrep`, for example, to only obtain `disk0s4`:

```
echo "Device Node: /dev/disk0s4" | pcregrep -o "/dev/\K.*"
```

It will return:

```
disk0s4
```

The option `-o` is for showing only the part of the line that matched a pattern instead of the whole line.

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left before it and return only the right part.